# Android Map View Issues on emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, android-mapview

i have create app wherein i use the MapView to render the google maps on the device. this works fine. though had few issues with the "X" marks appearing on the screen, that was resolved by commenting/removing the setSatelliteView(true) and setStreetView(true). now i mainly want the map to be rendered even on the emulator as few examples portray it. i have done the following:
1. map API key is correct in all pages.
2. apk generated using the debugKeystore
3. added the proxy setting in the emulator and able to access internet using emulator.
4. added -http-proxy http://192.68.100.101:8080/ in the run configuration-->target tab-->additional command line.

but again somehow i am unable to get the map rendered on the emulator.
pls help.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the issue where I was behind corporate firewall. I asked the IT team to provide a proxy server which can connect Internet and does not require any authentication. This was a tough request but was eventually fulfilled.

By settig proxy details in Emulator for Android 3.1 I was able to run the map on Emulator. The proxy does not work on any Android version less than 3.1

Comment: thanks buddy!! though its weired, it works :) thanks a lot :) \m/

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm the following

Internet is working on your machine
Your PC is not behind any corporate \ personel firewall
You do not use proxy to connect to Internet
You can access Internet using emulator

Comment: Sorry. Yes i am behind a corporate firewall